# Firefox 11 Bookmarks Toolbar too tall

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css

After updating to Firefox 11, my Bookmarks Toolbar is unpleasantly tall. [This link](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2443799) implies that it's due to the presence of separators in my toolbar. I tried adding the suggested CSS in post 5 to my userChrome.css file, but this did nothing.

I have also tried:

```
#PersonalToolbar {max-height:10px !important;}
```

However this simply truncates the bottom of the toolbar.

Does anyone know how to change the size of the bookmarks toolbar to match Firefox 10?

Here is a screenshot of my Bookmarks Toolbar:

[image]

I'm using OS X 10.6.8 with the default theme. I have "View > Toolbars > Customize > Use small icons" enabled. I'm also using the LiveClick 0.4.2.0 extension, but disabling it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Which operating system? Which theme (e.g. Windows Classic, Aero)? Do you have `View > Toolbars > Customize > Use small icons` enabled?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm having a hard time replicating this. With many folders and separators in different locations, the Bookmarks toolbar ends up being the same height in both Firefox 10 and 11.

Comment: Thanks for the replies; I've added more details to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CSS posted at mozillaZine Forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2443799#p11836349) works for me. Have you removed and re-added the separators to verify they are the cause? Doublecheck that you copied the CSS correctly and have not introduced any other error. (Your managing to truncate the toolbar shows that you had a working userChrome.css.) To test that the CSS works in a fresh Firefox profile, you can make a new profile using the profile manager (which can be started with the command `open -b org.mozilla.firefox --args -ProfileManager` in the Terminal, after first quitting Firefox).

Comment: Thanks, I had a CSS error elsewhere in the profile (tried to comment out a line with "//" )

Comment: @tba, CSS comments begin with a `/*` and end with a `*/`. The `//` is not part of CSS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on 10.6.8 with default theme. The solution for me came from your own post. When I removed the single separator I had in my Bookmarks Toolbar, it reverted to normal height. Your screenshot shows that you have at least two separators. Try removing them.

Comment: But I want separators.

Comment: Your actual question was "Does anyone know how to change the size of the bookmarks toolbar to match Firefox 10?", and you pretty much answered it yourself.